# SEO in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, seo, ngroute

I have a web site that includes one page per section. That is to say that every section have one page with her own meta tags.

How do I route all sections in one page with AngularJS without lose presence in finders being currently every section has her own meta tag description?

Comment: you need url routing in HTML5 mode , then the crawlbots can be able to crawl ur site and able to hold the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NgMeta](https://github.com/vinaygopinath/ngMeta) can help you.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, ngMetaProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home-template.html',
    data: {
      meta: {
        'title': 'Home page',
        'description': 'This is the description shown in Google search results'
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login-template.html',
    data: {
      meta: {
        'title': 'Login page',
        'titleSuffix': ' | Login to YourSiteName',
        'description': 'Login to the site'
      }
    }
  });
  ...
});
```